# Path not visible under UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions - SpriteKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm drawing a path in my SKScene to show the track of my object. 
Everything works fine, I can draw the path for all points and add it to scene.
The problem happens when I try to printscreen my scene, everything appears but the path.
Where am i doing it wrong?

```
- (void)drawPathTrackBall
{
    // length of my nsmutablearray with the object track
    NSUInteger len = [_trackBallPath count];

    // start image context
    CGRect bounds = self.scene.view.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    // draw my path
    SKShapeNode *line = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
    CGMutablePathRef linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, _ballStartX, _ballStartY);

    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        NSValue *nsPoint = [_trackBallPath objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint p = nsPoint.CGPointValue;
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, p.x, p.y);
    }

    line.path = linePath;
    line.lineWidth = 0.5f;
    line.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];

    [_container addChild:line];

    _screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Thanx

Comment: You are probably missing to set the size/frame of the line node

Comment: I don't think so, coz i add the line node to scene, and its visible and size ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - you're creating simple path, its not connected or drawed to somewhere in your code to context. I didn't learn SpriteKit yet, but I know CoreGraphics well and I think you just can't simply use there SpriteKit API to create a screenshot. Instead try to use native CoreGraphics methods.

To make your code work you need:

- Obtain context to which you will draw.
- As you've already created a path - just add it to context.
- Then stroke/fill it.

To obtain current context to draw call: `CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();`

To add path use : `CGContextAddPath(ctx, path);`

To stroke/fill use `CGContextStrokePath(ctx);` / `CGContextFillPath(ctx);`

So your updated code should look like(notice I've removed code related to SpriteKit stuff):

```
- (void)drawPathTrackBall
{
    // length of my nsmutablearray with the object track
    NSUInteger len = [_trackBallPath count];

    // start image context
    CGRect bounds = self.scene.view.bounds;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
    [self.view drawViewHierarchyInRect:bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(); // Obtain context to draw.
    CGMutablePathRef linePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathMoveToPoint(linePath, NULL, _ballStartX, _ballStartY);

    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<len; ++i)
    {
        NSValue *nsPoint = [_trackBallPath objectAtIndex:i];
        CGPoint p = nsPoint.CGPointValue;
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(linePath, NULL, p.x, p.y);
    }

    // I've exchanged SpriteKit node API calls with CoreGraphics equivalents.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.5f); 
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, linePath);
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    _screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Try it.

Comment: Thanks a lot Yuri, this should work. I will try.
But my script runs, I tried to put un NSTimer with a 0.1 delay and it works. 

If I draw the path and then after 0.1s I call the method will copy the screen, it works. 

The problem is: I want to create an imagem with the screen and the path together, but I don't want to show the path in my view. If I delete my path after print the view, it flicks because it has existed for 1 second.

Comment: If I correctly understood your problem - you get correct image but your view also has a path drawed in it and you don't want it to be there, only in image?

If so - my code is applicable for creating screenshot, don't use it instead of your SpriteKit existed code. (Assuming that you also replaced all sprite kit api calls with core graphics equivalents.)

Comment: Hi Yuri, yeah! that's it!. I only had to change the values from Y because in Spritekit the bottom of the screen has y-coordinate 0. Thanx